# Partial Derivative of f w.r.t y = 0, does the Initial Value Problem has a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given this IVP to check if it has a unique solution:

$$y' = \frac{|\sin y|}{x^2-1} = f(x,y), x_{0} = 0, y_{0} = 0$$

I obtained $$f_{y} = \frac{\cos(y)\sin(y)}{(x^2-1)|\sin(y)|}$$ and since this will be $0$ under the initial conditions, does that mean that this IVP has a unique solution?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The function is not $y$-differentiable at that point. You need to go back to Lipschitz continuity. Then you get that
$$
\bigl||\sin y_1|-|\sin y_2|\bigr|\le |\sin y_1-\sin y_2|\le\left|\cos\frac{y_1+y_2}2\right||y_1-y_2|,
$$
so that you get indeed a $y$-global Lipschitz constant.